# How to calc this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am supposed to calculate this series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(4n²+8n+3)}$$
I couldn't do it exactly, actually. I saw that:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1/2}{(n+1)^2} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(4n²+8n+3)} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1/2}{(n^2)}$$

And i know that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^2)} = \pi/6$$

So that, the only answer between the alternatives (It was a question with alternatives) that satisfy this condition is $1/3$, which after i put on the wolframalpha it is really the result. But i would like to know how to calc the answer exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{4n^2+8n+3}=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}.$$
The sum should telescope.